# how to fix my intent when i put the parameters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

[image: that is the error message]i get some problem when i use the intent, he said "cannot resolve constructor Intent('....')" , i dont know what is wrong in my code but you can see what i m importing here

```
package com.example.noen.myintentapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_move:
                 Intent intn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,target1.class);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the full, exact error message?

Comment: @MikeM. cannot resolve constructor Intent

Comment: No, there's more than that.

Comment: @MikeM. nothing, i dont know what happen in my code, i think that is has corrected

Comment: Yes, that is correct, which is why we need the full, exact error message to figure out what the issue is. It has to be telling something about expected arguments.

Comment: you are not putting any param here add your code and screenshot of error

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project (look under the Build menu)? If that doesn't fix it, try Invalidate Cache/Restart, under the File menu.

Comment: @MikeM. error message is " cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.noen.myintenapp.MainActivity, java.lang.Class<com.example.noen.myintentapp.target1>)' "

Comment: Did you try the suggestions above?

Comment: @MikeM. yes i did, but not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all of the `import` statements at the top of `MainActivity`.

Comment: yes, i have edited @MikeM.

Comment: Something is really wrong with your IDE, then. Here's your code in a test project, with dummy items for the layout and `View`s: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Pyw.png.

Comment: @MikeM. should i update my IDE?

Comment: Yeah, I'd try that first, but I'm not very optimistic that that will do it. You might have to uninstall and reinstall it. Actually, the first thing I would do it start over with a fresh project, and just copy your code over into that. See what happens.